# Ayuda para verificar que los campo del formulario no estén vacíos

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

**Hola, quisiera conocer el código javascript para verificar que los campos de mi formulario no sean enviados vacíos y como integrarlo a el.
Mi formulario es este.**

**Mi formulario es el siguiente:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Formulario de Registro</title>
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="form-register">
    <h4>Registro</h4>
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="nombres" id="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese sus Nombres">
    <input class="controls" type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese sus Apellidos">
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Ingrese su Correo">
    <input class="controls" type="email" name="repetircorreo" id="repetircorreo" placeholder="Verifique correo">
    <input class="controls" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
     <input class="controls" type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Verifique Contraseña">
   <center> (Aqui ira el capchat)</center>
    <input class="botons" type="submit" value="Registrarse">
    <p><a href="#">¿Ya tiene cuenta? Click Aqui</a></p>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar el tag required

```
<input class="controls" type="email" name="repetircorreo" id="repetircorreo" placeholder="Verifique correo" required>
```

esto hara que sea obligatorio rellenar el campo, ahora si quieres hacer una validacion mas especifica y amigable visualmente para el usuario, puedes usar la libreria de JQUERY VALIDATION https://jqueryvalidation.org/

pero tiene problemas con el dinamismo.
otra forma es con javascript puro, simplemente comparando los valores de cada elemento con operadores:

```
var nombres=document.getElementById("nombres").value;
if(nombres != ""){
  alert("el campo no esta vacio");
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero aguegue el codigo a mi formulario para probarlo y igual se envio sin el nombre. loe agregue dentro de la etiqueta <head>  ```<script>
var nombres=document.getElementById("nombres").value;
if(nombres != ""){
  alert("el campo no esta vacio");
}
</script> ```

Comment: lo hice con la etiqueta tag required pero esta etique tambien se puede agregar al capchat?